# Getting error when creating a file with echo in my script

Tags: linux, bash

NEW TO LINUX:
I have this script creating a file directory and at each level creating a file called "Year" with a date stored inside. But when I go to create the "Year" file I keep getting "No such file or directory" as my error

command generating error:

echo "1972" > /ResearchUnix/Year

[image: My Script at the moment]

Comment: Isn't `mkdir -p ResearchUnix/{BSD/{NextStep/MacOSX,FreeBSD},Commercial/Solaris}` easier? Brace expansion works fine for this. Then you will simply need to loop over each target directory echoing your year into `Year`.

Answer (score 3):

Getting "No such file or directory" when trying to create a file means that the directory that you're trying to create it in doesn't exist. In the command you gave, that would be the /ResearchUnix/ directory. Note that "ResearchUnix" and "/ResearchUnix" aren't the same unless your current directory is "/". Either add the "/" in front of all of the mkdir's, or remove it in the echo.